# запустить js скрипт в c#

Tags: javascript, c#

пытаюсь запустить жску с помощью Noesis.Javascript, пример :

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\js.js");
        string script = sr.ReadToEnd();

        JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext();
        context.Run(script);

        object num = context.Run("C();");
        MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
```

сама жска [тык](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/login/fwcim._CB271035486_.js)
проблема в том, что при запуске скрипта ( context.Run(script);) выдает ошибки, такие как "window is not defined", "document is not defined" и тп. Можете подсказать, как решить ?

Comment: это объекты специфичные для браузера. Используй браузер. Либо убери их использование из скрипта.

Comment: и вот тут [пример, как добавлять объекты](https://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home)

Comment: спасибо, наверно лучше юзать браузер, ибо жс генерирует метадату, а она от данных с бр зависит, по идее. Кстати, не поможете с примером ? в частности с моим случаем, тобишь, не совсем стандартным

Comment: по ссылке какой-то большой минифицированный скрипт, в нем придется долго разбираться. чтобы просто понять что в нем происходит

Comment: изначально, мне нужен параметр metadata1, для авторизации, путем клика и сниффера нашел эту жс, хотя я совсем плохо понимаю жс, но она очень похожа не генерацию того самого metadata1

https://note-pad.net/ru/read/fb009220d65921f4b9ca01546c68a20d?page=1

Comment: ага, тогда все проще - выбираешь только ту часть скрипта, которая нужна, а честь где он в сам инпут пихает - удаляешь и все

Comment: я все же думаю, что нужно запускать это именно в бр, вот эта функция http://pastebin.com/9PeMdXbF эта функция содержит еще +100500 функций внутри, внизу они вызываются по порядку. Как я понял, главная подфункция - это C(); , она уже от готовых данных склеивает и записывает в aq. Но данные берутся из самого браузера. Если запустить немного переделанный скрипт (убрал в С() функции создание инпута и тп), то вылезает ошибка "Unexpected token < " при запуске

Comment: я буду бесконечно вам признателен, если вы мне поможете в этом разобраться, ибо один я чет не вдупляю ((